# Magento2.0 used as backend and Wordpress used as frontend(magento2.0 Api)

Tags: magento2, wordpress

I need solution with below requirement

1) All Magento data, inclusive of  catalog/products, inventory, customer data, quotes, checkout process, etc., should be utilized from within WordPress by way of the Magento 2 REST API

2) Magento should exist solely as a back-end service. It should have nothing to do with rendering the front-end at any point in the user experience